# Using Angular binding the name of ngModelGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

My question is how should I bind my input data to `ngModelGroup`'s `name` property?

I am learning angular and trying to write a JSON editor. I've read [API / @angular/forms/NgModelGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModelGroup).

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="groupName" [(ngModel)]="modelname" #input>{{modelname}}
  <span class="input-group-addon">add model name</span>
</div>
<form #loginForm="ngForm" >
  <fieldset ngModelGroup="definitions">
    <fieldset [ngModelGroup]="modelname" #nameCtrl="ngModelGroup">
      <hr>
      <div>{{nameCtrl.name}}</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" ngModel name="type">
        <span class="input-group-addon">add model type like object</span>
      </div>
      <fieldset ngModelGroup="properties">
        <fieldset ngModelGroup="model ID">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" ngModel name="type">
            <input type="text" ngModel name="id">
            <span class="input-group-addon">add properties id&type</span>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <div>{{loginForm.value | json}}</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Now when I change the input of `modelname`, the name of `ngModelGroup` has changed.  But `{{loginForm.value | json}}` still shows the previous data.

I've tried `ngOnChanges` and also failed to change the loginForm value.

This is my loginForm.value, I want to have a real-time change with `model name`. Could you please tell me if there is a way to make this work?

```
{ "definitions": { "model name": { "type": "object", "properties": { "model ID": { "type": "pid", "id": "ptype" } } } } }
```